# C++ Trouble compiling cout with a += statement

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am writing this beginner program:

[image: my program]

I keep on running to this problem:

if I try to run cout << x *= y += z -= 4 << endl; then I get this response from the compiler:

prog.cpp:6:35: error: invalid operands of types 'int' and '' to binary 'operator<<'
  cout << x *= y += z -= 4 << std::endl;
                                   ^

The cout function works fine when I try something like cout << x+y << endl.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Put the equation netween the two << in brackets () and you will be fine. And after that please google `c++ standard input and output`

Comment: Please do not write code like that.

Comment: `int x, y, z = 6;` only sets `z` to 6. The other two are uninitialized and you're getting undefined behavior by using them.

Comment: Alright thanks I see what i did wrong

Comment: When you post a question, place the code and error message into the question **as text**. If the mistake is non-trivial, no one is ever going to retype your code just to try an build it for you.

Answer (score 6):

The operator `<<` has [lower precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `*=`, etc. Try putting the expression in brackets like this:

`cout << (x *= y += z -= 4) << endl;`